# What are ways to play a sound in PhantomJS/CasperJS?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I've been searching the web for more than 3 hours now looking for relevant ways to play an audio file but unfortunately I can't find anything useful. I have a CasperJS that's automating some tasks and I wanted it to play an audio file (e.g. beep.wav) after it completes all the tasks. I wonder if it's possible.

```
casper.run(function(casper) {
    fs.write( saveDir, JSON.stringify(content, null, '  '), 'w');
    // play an audio file before exiting....
    casper.exit();
});
```

Comment: `PJS` has no window.Audio function, maybe you need to use `SlimerJS`

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Yes, thank you for suggesting. I'll try to explore it if there are not other ways around it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Child Process Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/) to run your script, to play the music.

I created `pl.sh` script to play the music:

```
#!/bin/bash
mplayer "/music/downloads2/Technoboy - Into Deep.oga"
exit 0
```

Then I created CasperJS script:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper
.start('http://domu-test-2/node/12', function(){
    var childProcess;
    try {
        childProcess = require("child_process")
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e, "(error)")
    }
    if (childProcess){
        childProcess.execFile("/bin/bash", ["./pl.sh"], null, function(err, stdout, stderr){
            console.log("execFileSTDOUT: "+stdout);
            console.log("execFileSTDERR:",stderr);
        });
        console.log("Shell commands executed")
    } else {
        console.log("Unable to require child process (error)")
    } 
    this.wait(10000)// need to wait to play the sound
})
.run();
```

And then PhantomJS script:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://domu-test-2/node/12', function() {
    var childProcess;
    try {
        childProcess = require("child_process")
    } catch(e){ 
        console.log(e, "(error)")
    }
    if (childProcess){
        childProcess.execFile("/bin/bash", ["./pl.sh"], null, function(err, stdout, stderr){
            console.log("execFileSTDOUT: "+stdout);
            console.log("execFileSTDERR:",stderr);
        });
        console.log("Shell commands executed")
    } else {
        console.log("Unable to require child process (error)")
    } 

    setTimeout(phantom.exit,10000)// need to wait to play the sound
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Igor! this worked like a charm! I'm on a OSX system so I had to modify your bash script to use 'afplay' instead of 'mplayer'.